# Make UploadFS work with angular2-meteor

Tags: javascript, database, meteor, typescript, angular2-meteor

I happen to need a file storage database and `UploadFS` seems to be the best option. My project is in Angular2 typescript and Meteor.

`meteor add jalik:ufs-gridfs`

So far it fails when I try to import the library like this:

`import {UploadFS} from 'meteor/jalik:ufs'`

The error thrown sais it couldn't find the library (on the client side).

I thought it may be because the library is in `javascript` while the rest of the project in `typescript` so I tried to write a stub `ufs.d.ts`, first handcrafted, then with [dstmake](https://github.com/ConquestArrow/dtsmake), and then by hand again when I found I had to export the module `UploadFS` so that meteor (barbatus:typescript?) could see it:

```
declare module 'meteor/jalik:ufs' {
    export module UploadFS{
        interface UploadFS {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So far I had my `ufs.d.ts` stub file at the `typings/` folder and linked in the `main.d.ts`. No errors at compile time. Meteor sad the DB was correctly created ... but then when I tried to use it broke.

I found that UploadFS was undefined so I supposed it wasn't referencing the library even though Meteor compiled without any error.

So I suppose the only thing I've have left is to translate `jalik:ufs` and `jalik:ufs-gridfs` to typescript by hand. Is that correct? Is there an easier way of making ufs work wit angular2-meteor?

Would you use some other storage solution? any advice either fixing this library or choosing another one?

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the package, I haven't migrated it to the new syntax (Meteor 1.3.x) with ECMAS6, you know with import/export commands, maybe that would help ?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to Meteor. I'll give it a look along the summer as I'm relying on your library for some core stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { UploadFS } from 'meteor/jalik:ufs';
console.log('UploadFS', UploadFS);
```

This gives me the `UploadFS` object and I think it's totally independent of `angular2-meteor` so I suppose that `jalik:ufs` should be working fine, even with those warnings generated by ts compiler.

About typings, those warning are very annoying, I know :) but you can pretend for now you don't see them.

Here's an example implementation of `jalik:ufs` I made for Angular1, but it will look pretty much the same with Angular2.

http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/handling-files-with-collectionfs

Comment: You where right. But as I was seeing the errors I thought it couldn't work, so I didn't even check.

Answer (score 3):

I'm successfully importing that library and just suppressing the warnings with this line:

```
import 'meteor/jalik:ufs'; declare let UploadFS:any;
```

Keep an eye on https://github.com/meteor-typings and https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/102 for proper type definitions in the future.

You should never have to re-implement a JavaScript library in TypeScript in order to use it.